# How initialization is work as Condition in C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h >
void main (){
int a = 0, b = 1, c = 2;
*(( a+1 == 1) ? & b : &a ) = a ? b : c;
printf ("%d , %d, %d\n ", a, b , c );
}
```

Explanation:

```
*(& b ) = a ? b : c ;
b = a ? b : c ;
b = 0 ? 1 : 2 ;  //problem is here
b = 2
```

I have doubt in 2nd last line of explanation that, how b = 0 condition goes wrong and it gives b = 2 . why not b = 1 ? Sorry in case anything i missed.

Comment: Why would anyone initialize variables like this?

Comment: I think you're missing that `b = 0 ? 1 : 2` means `b = (0 ? 1 : 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator has higher precedence than the assignment operator. Due to that,

```
b = 0 ? 1 : 2 ;
```

is interpreted as:

```
b = (0 ? 1 : 2) ;
```

not as:

```
(b = 0) ? 1 : 2 ;
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence for further details on operator precedence in C.

Answer (score 1):

> b = 0 ? 1 : 2;  //problem is here
>
> I have doubt in 2nd last line of explaination that, how b = 0 condition goes wrong and it gives b = 2 . why not b = 1 ?

Because `=` is assignment operator (NOT logical operator `==`) and it has lower priority than conditional operator `?`. So in fact that expression is the same as:

```
b = ( 0 ? 1 : 2 );
```

Now it's typical conditional operator, and because 0 is false, then `b` is assigned to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = 0 ? 1 : 2
```

Due to operator order of precedence the above line is equivalent to:

```
b = (0 ? 1 : 2)
```

That is, the `?:` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator. So finally, the above can be rewritten as:

```
if (0) {
    b = 1;
} else {
    b = 2;
}
```

And hence `b = 2` is the final result.

Answer (score 0):

> I have doubt in 2nd last line of explaination that, how b = 0 condition goes wrong and it gives b = 2 . why not b = 1 ?

```
b = 0 ? 1 : 2 ;  //problem is here
```

In this `b=0` is not condition. As ternary operator has more precedence than assignment operator `=` , therefore ,it is evaluated first .

So, `0?1:2` in this as condition is `0` , i.e false ,therefore,`b` is equal to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean:

```
b = !b ? 1 : 2;
```

,which let b become 1 when b was zero, and 2 when b is non-zero.

Or:

```
(b==b) ? 1 : 2;
```

,which evaluates to 1 when b was zero, and 2 when b is non-zero.